# MCP add external Libraries

Tags: java, minecraft

I have in my Minecraft Client a function, that needs a external library. I added it in the IDE and added it at the lib/ folder, but it doesnt help. Has anyone experience with this? They are 2 jars.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to add the library to your classpath.
The best way to do tat would be to add it as a dependency in your build.gradle and run `gradle eclipse` or `gradle idea`, depending on your IDE, so it automatically creates the classpath.

Comment: So...without the Forge API? o.ô So what are you doing, actually?

Comment: I do MCP, its the Client modification.

Comment: Isn't "MCP" the Minecraft Coder Pack in this case?

Comment: Yes. But it isnt Forge

Comment: Okay, even in that case you might still want to use a build tool tomanage your classpath. Or write it by hand and tell everyone to download dependencies on their own. ;)

Comment: What is a build tool?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). They are a little much to get into, but are kind of worth it in the long run. Mostly, they manage dependencies, but especially gradle comes with a whole scripting language for builds. I mean, you can life without them, but at some point, managing libraries etc. becomes tedious with Java.

Comment: Well, at least Forge uses Gradle, I haven't actually used MCP without that.